# gnuplot: date and time in separate columns for x axis, sorting input file

Tags: gnuplot

Let me set the stage in order:

Previously I was plotting only for a single day (today.dat) that looks like this:

```
2017-05-02    12:00:25    24.5
2017-05-02    12:01:26    25.2
2017-05-02    12:02:27    29.2
```

so I just used column 2, with this program (minus the limit lines for brevity) and output:

```
set title "24V PV Battery Bank"
set xlabel "Time"
set ylabel "Volts"
set grid
unset mouse
unset log
unset key
set timestamp
set xdata time
set timefmt '%H:%M:%S'
set xticks format '%H:%M'
plot "today.dat" using 2:$3 with lines lc rgb 'red' t 'battery'
```

[image]

Then at midnight each night I copy today.dat into an Archive directory with each file named by the date, like 2017-05-02.dat, 2017-05-03.dat, etc...

So far, so good.

---

...but now I have concatenated all those daily files into all.dat

```
cat Archive/*.dat >all.dat
```

which looks like this:

```
2017-05-02    12:00:25    24.5
2017-05-02    12:01:26    25.2
2017-05-02    12:02:27    29.2
2017-05-02    15:00:12    29.2
2017-05-04    12:01:32    24.7
2017-05-04    12:02:35    24.7
2017-05-04    12:03:37    24.7
2017-05-03    12:00:45    24.6
2017-05-03    12:01:46    24.6
2017-05-03    12:02:47    24.7
```

So I need to know how to use both columns 1 and 2 in the x-axis.

Also, since I don't know how cat works on whole directories full of the daily files, I am not sure they have concatenated in sequential days, so maybe will need to be able to sort all.dat?

Questions:

1)  How do I put the original columns 1 and 2 together as the x-axis?  (Even if it takes running a pre-processing program to do so, then so be it)

2)  How do I sort the file on two tab-delimited columns to make sure they are sequential.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for the answers.  It was hard to pick just one for the accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regards to using two column dates, you just tell Gnuplot about them, e.g.:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%m/%d\n%H:%M"
plot 'all.dat' using 1:3 with lines
```

Results in:

[image: Result of unsorted plot]

Depending on your shell the asterisk (`*`) will list files in lexicographical order, so you should be okay. However, there are easy ways around it if the output is unsorted, e.g. add sort to the plot command:

```
plot '<sort all.dat' using 1:3 with lines
```

Results in:

[image: Result of sorted plot]

Comment: I like this answer best because it uses gnuplot to perform the operation.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use `awk` to format data. Here we get strings like `2017-05-02_12:00:25 24.5` piped to the `sort` command. `awk` prints first and second columns separated by "_" followed by third column. These strings are sorted and redirected to gnuplot.

```
set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S'
set format x "%m/%d\n%H:%M"
plot "<awk '{print $1\"_\"$2\" \"$3}' tm.dat |sort" u 1:2 w l
```

[image]

Comment: I like your answer.  Thank you.  It taught me a lot about what can be in the filename portion of the plot command.